# Possibilities to embed Latex in QML

Tags: qt, latex, qml, text-rendering

I'm doing a presentation system in QML (with C++ backend) similar to [this one](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/05/30/a-qml-presentation-system/).

I want to be able to include some Latex code to display some math (only minimum Latex capabilities needed, such as sums, fractions, super- and substript and math fonts).

I see the following possibilities to do so:

- Using *latex2e*:

  1. Compile the Latex code to a DVI document (with `latex`)
  2. Convert the DVI to SVG (with `dvisvgm`)
  3. Display this using an `Image` in QML (which also supports SVG)

- Using *MathJax*:

  1. Wrap the Latex code in a small HTML file + include the MathJax JS library
  2. Display this using `WebKit` for QML

- Custom solution (C++):

  1. Write or include an existing minimal Latex math parser
  2. Write a `QDeclarativeItem` with custom painting

Is there another solution I don't see? I prefer the first solution as the second sounds too heavy and the third too hard.

I see the following problem with the **baseline** of the math formula: I want to be able to include inline formulas (within a paragraph). Currently, text paragraphs are renderd using a QML Text element. Is there a possibility to include an image in a Text element (using HTML img element maybe) with a *specified baseline*? Also, how can I determine the baseline of a rendered Latex document?

Note: The time to pre-render Latex code isn't problematic. I'm going to cache already rendered formulas, so it should be no problem to invoke `latex` + `dvisvgm` on every single formula contained in the presentation document.

Also note that I use a preprocessor (I don't write the QML code by hand but generate it). So I don't need a QML element for the Latex code but I can just generate a QML code snippet with an Image element (for the first solution). This should simplify embedding the rendered image.

I also don't need to support wrapping a formula when using inline Latex. (Latex does so when writing inline formulas, but I only use small formulas I don't want to be wrapped anyways.)

Comment: I would be interested in hearing which way you went and whether it worked for your purposes as we're also hitting that issue.

Comment: I used approach 1. To embed the rendered images in paragraphs (inline), I've split the text of each paragraph in single words and placed them manually with a custom flow layout algorithm. Images can then be manually positioned. If I find time, I'll write this as an answer with enough details. By the way, SVG doesn't work very well, I used rasterized PNG format for this. My app can readjust the rendered resolution (i.e. reconvert the image) when the image is scaled, so you almost don't notice it's a rasterized image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think those are three good options, and I can't think of any other way to do it.

It sounds like you have a requirement to have the formulas in-line with some textual paragraphs, so for that reason I think option 2 is a good way to do it.

It isn't difficult to use the WebKit component. I'm not sure what you mean by "too heavy".

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a rich text QML component which also supports images (e.g. TextEdit) rather than Image - then you can place them inline with normal text.

Comment: I tried this approach, but the problem is that the images are always vertically aligned at the baseline. When the image is a latex formula with a subset letter or something similar, which should go below the baseline, that doesn't work.